See what packages are installed in apt, but not as a dependency
I want a list of all installed packages that can not be picked up by autoremove
For example firefox would also install xul-ext-ubufox if you remove firefox you can use apt-get autoremove to remove xul-ext-ubufox, but not if you used apt-get install firefox xul-ext-ubufox

would the Synaptic Package Manager software not provide that information?
